# Getting Lucene Score for part of a retrieved Doc

Tags: lucene

I get a lot of wiki page and I want to train a classifier to see whether it is possible to determine the location to focus on searching by a handful of features including the location of a paragraph and lucene score for the paragraph. I have tried treating each paragraph as a document and that enables me to get the lucene score for each paragraph. However, this runs the risk of retrieving all paragraphs from too few number of pages. Is that a way to use pages as documents for storage and then get the lucene score not for the pages but a part of a page? Many thanks.

Clarification:

I first do the following:
    Doc:  wiki page
    Doc.field: wiki page id
    Doc.field: wiki page title
    Doc.field: wiki page text

I want to test my instinct that most hits come from the first paragraph by a classifier that uses lucene score and location as each paragraph's feature.

Now I try the following:
    Doc: wiki para
    Doc.field: a paragaraph taken from the text of a wiki page
    Doc.field: wiki page id+ "-" + paragraph counter (title = 0)

Treating paragraph as documents, I can get the lucene score for each paragraph but I am losing most of pages retrieved by the 1st approach because 10 hits now means 10 paragraphs, mostly from the first 1 or 2 pages retrieved by the 1st approach.

Is there a way to get the lucene score of each paragraph of the pages retrieved by the 1st approach? Many thanks.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what outcome you want. It sounds like you are searching within a wiki page and want to find a particular area of the page to display. Is that right?

Comment: It also sounds like you are searching multiple pages, but then I'm not sure what's the purpose of breaking up the paragraphs. There might be a fun question in there, so it would be nice to clarify for those of us who like to work with Lucene.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have clarified my message a bit. I hope it is now comprehensible

Answer (score 1):

You can use approach, where you are treating a paragraph as a single document. To avoid risk of retrieving all paragraphs from too few number of pages you can use [DiversifiedTopDocsCollector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/misc/org/apache/lucene/search/DiversifiedTopDocsCollector.html). See example below

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = 
                          new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
    Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);

    addDoc(indexWriter, "test1", 1L);
    addDoc(indexWriter, "test1 test2", 1L);
    addDoc(indexWriter, "test1 test2 test3", 2L);
    addDoc(indexWriter, "test1 test3", 2L);
    addDoc(indexWriter, "test1 test3", 2L);
    indexWriter.commit();

    search(indexWriter, 1);

    System.out.println("\n");
    search(indexWriter, 2);
}

private static void search(IndexWriter indexWriter, 
                           final int maxHitsPerKey) throws IOException {
    final IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    DiversifiedTopDocsCollector collector = 
                          new DiversifiedTopDocsCollector(10, maxHitsPerKey) {
      @Override
      protected NumericDocValues getKeys(LeafReaderContext leafReaderContext) {
            try {
                return leafReaderContext.reader().getNumericDocValues("pageId");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };

    indexSearcher.search(new TermQuery(new Term("paragraph", "test1")), 
                              collector);
    TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs();
    for (ScoreDoc sd : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
        Document document = indexReader.document(sd.doc);
        System.out.println(sd.doc + " " + 
                            sd.score + " " + 
                            document.getField("pageId").stringValue());
    }
}

private static void addDoc(IndexWriter indexWriter, 
                           String value, 
                           Long id) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("paragraph", value, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new LongField("pageId", id, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new NumericDocValuesField("pageId", id));
    indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Program will output following

```
0 0.81767845 1
3 0.51104903 2


0 0.81767845 1
1 0.51104903 1
3 0.51104903 2
4 0.51104903 2
```